# Issue or Bug. The shading of an object changes when deselected in "Smooth" mode. (Why Radeon Users May Want to Avoid Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: mesh, objects, interface, 3d-view, shaders

Issue or Bug. The shading of an object changes (to Flat) when deselected in "Smooth" mode.

These changes only appear to the unselected objects in the scene in object mode.

It's like the object turns back to flat when deselected. Things also look/appear to be a sort of triangulated.

Has anybody encountered this same issue?

Is it a bug or a new feature I've overlooked?

(I'm using an old AMD/ATI Readon with Ubuntu 16.04)

**UPDATE:**

**Seems they have stopped working on new drivers for AMD Ubuntu 16.04, Link:** *http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04*

**DON'T TRY TO INSTALL DRIVERS FROM OTHER UBUNTU DISTRO'S, YOU CAN GET SYSTEM FAILURES**

[image: Picture#1]

[image: Picture#2]

[image: Picture#3]

[image: Picture#4]

[image: Picture#5]

[image: Picture#6]

[image: Picture#7]

**UPDATE 31-05-2016**

JUST SOMETHING WEIRD...

[image: 001]

[image: 002]

I have no idea why, but recently stumbled on this weird thing.

(PS: all objects have been set to smooth)

Also I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside my 16.04 distro, so I can continue without this bug.

Comment: I think it's a Ubuntu 16.04 issue. I've tried several packages from blender.org and Graphicall.org. Still having the same problem. Also the Additional Driver is not the same as when I used Ubuntu 14.04. I gotta check for alternative drivers since the Xorg Linux driver is also not listed.

Comment: The choices I can make at the "Additional Drivers" tab are "Using processor microcode firmware for amd cpus from amd64-microcode" or "Do not use this device".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the RC of Blender 2.78. The bug seems to be gone... :)

Link: http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.78/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If Blender 3D is running fine on your Linux distro and your considering about upgrading to the latest Linux distro (in my situation to Ubuntu 16.04).

**First check if they have released new drivers or if there even are drivers that support your upgrade.**

**Especially for AMD/ATI/Readon Graphic cards, you may want to stick to your current OS version.**

**They have stopped working on new drivers for AMD Ubuntu 16.04,**

*Link: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04*

**Also useful**

*Link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/744050/im-using-ubuntu-16-04-and-theres-no-fglrx*

*Link: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes#fglrx*

**UPDATE 31-05-2016**

**Some interesting new developments:** AMD's gaming-optimized AMDGPU-PRO driver for Linux is in beta.

*Link: http://www.pcworld.com/article/3075837/linux/amds-gaming-optimized-amdgpu-pro-driver-for-linux-is-in-beta.html*

Still in Beta and won't support GPUs older/lower than the Radeon HD 7000 series.

Ubuntu still recommends sticking with Ubuntu 14.04.